# Angular2 + 3rd party datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am having some issues with a 3rd party input (for dates).

In the view i have..

```
      <label class="spark-input spark-date" [ngClass]="{'active': userInformation.BirthDateString != ''}">
        <input class="spark-input__field" type="date" role="textbox" [(ngModel)]="BirthDateString">
        <span class="spark-label">What is your birth date?</span>
      </label>
```

In the component..

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-profile',
  templateUrl: '../app/my-profile/my-profile.component.html'
})
export class MyProfileComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  public BirthDateString = "";

ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.spark-date').sparkDateInput({onChange : this.OnChange});
}

  OnChange(value,inputInstance){
    this.BirthDateString = "value";
  }
```

The first issue i have is that despite of [(ngModel)]="BirthDateString", if i change BirthDate in the component i cant see it in the view and if i add a value in the view i see it as undifined in the component.

The second issue i see is that the component execute an event when the input changes. i subscribed OnChange function to that event. When the event is executed, "this" is undefined.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried binding to the input instead?

Comment: I guess first issue can be solved by `changedetection` but for second issue i'm not sure but probably you could use `setTimeout`( not sure though).

Comment: Hi @Jai , i binded it using ngmodel directive

Comment: @micronyks still get the same result. I've just updated the post with an image